# Accessing liked images of instagram API with Angular

Tags: angularjs, instagram-api

I'm trying to access the JSON of the liked media of a particular instagram user,   in the documentation it says to use this:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

as mentioned here:
https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

replacing ACCESS-TOKEN with the one given by instagram which I've done below:

```
(function(){
      var app = angular.module('instafeed', []);
      app.factory("InstagramAPI", ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
          fetchPhotos: function(callback){
            var endpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked/?";
            endpoint += "?access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]";
            endpoint += "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

            $http.jsonp(endpoint).success(function(response){
              callback(response);

            });
          }
        }
      }]);

      app.controller('ShowImages', function($scope, InstagramAPI){
        $scope.layout = 'grid';
        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.pics = [];

        InstagramAPI.fetchPhotos(function(data){
          $scope.pics = data;
          console.log(data)
        });
      });

    })();
```

obviously I have replaced ACCESS-TOKEN with mine, but nothing is given back, is there something incorrect?

EDIT: I added the callback but still it comes back as undefined.

Comment: Your endpoint has no callback, callbacks are required when using jsonp. Here's instagram's docs for jsonp requests: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Comment: thanks, I added endpoint += "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK"; so it is now:   var endpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked/?";
            endpoint += "?access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]"; but it still comes back as undefined.

Comment: Try callback(response).

Comment: You've used .success(callback), your res.data is passed to your callback directly.

Comment: thanks but now I get "Missing access_token URL parameter." I've edited the OP now.

Comment: One quick observation, remove the first '/?' from '.../liked/?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work using jsonp, add the following to your endpoint url:

```
&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

Your callback needs to be named 'JSON_CALLBACK'. Find out why here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

Otherwise, to make a simple GET request...

```
$http.get(endpoint).success(function(data){
     callback(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks but now I get "Missing access_token URL parameter."

Answer (score 0):

It's jsonp, so my guess is that you should **specify name of the callback function** in your URL:

```
var endpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked/?callback=callback";
```